# Como importar um projeto existente com angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular

Olá, fiz o download de um projeto em angular 4 com bootstrap css, agora gostaria de trabalhar nesse projeto, fazendo algumas alterações para efeito de estudo. Acontece que não sei como fazer um importe desse projeto já existente para executá-lo com o comando ng serve.

Comment: pode fornecer mais detalhes sobre o projeto? Você realizou um fork de um repositório no GitHub ou algo do tipo?

Comment: não é fork de nenhum projeto, só fiz o download. Só queria saber como fazer para o angular cli reconhece-lo como um projeto angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você deve ter o [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) instalado e, na pasta raiz do projeto (normalmente a src) você deve abrir um prompt de comando e rodar o comando *npm install* que realizará o download de todas as dependências desse projeto.

Para rodar esse comando no prompt, você precisa do [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) instalado também.

Após esse passos você roda um *ng serve* para subir o servidor local.